# Best way to deal with 'map' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that does this:

```
def number(self, width = None):

        if not self.v:
            return None

        if not width:
            width = len(self.v)

        return self.VERSION_DELIMITER.join(map(str, self.v[:width]))
```

I recently changed to using Python 3 instead of 2. When I did that I started getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable:
```

What is the best way to make this work in Python 3?

Comment: Can you share an example of the values of `self.v` and `width` and the output you're expecting to get for these values?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`self.v` is a map object, which are not subscriptable in Python 3. The easiest fix is to make it into a list before slicing:

```
map(str, list(self.v)[:width])
```

Depending on the rest of class implementation, it might be better to explicitly store `.v` as a list

Comment: Another way is to use `islice`: add the line `from itertools import islice` and then you can use `map(str, islice(self.v, width))`. This doesn't construct two temporary lists.

Comment: @Jasmijn that's definitely a better approach, can't believe I didn't know about this function. Would you mind posting it as an answer (I'll delete mine)?

Comment: @Marat this makes sense! Thanks

Comment: This won't work. `list(self.v)` will exhaust the `map` object the first time through, so it will be empty the next time. You're better off saving it as a list right away. The dupe I linked to goes over different options.